# XCode keeps revoking all my provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

We're working on the same project 2 persons. I don't understand why Apple forces the use of a "Development" profile, since develop isn't really supposed to be signed but whatevs. My issue is each time we compile on our machines, XCode invalidate existing provisioning profiles and create a "Managed" one.

Obviously this isn't XCode fault, but we failed to understand how it is supposed to work. Can we get an step by step on how to set up both development and production **on more than 1 machine, using the "Managed by XCode"** option, so we don't have to create a CSR each time? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The short answer? Don't manage your provisioning profiles with XCode, I myself and countless others have the same issue and the only way I found around it was to manage them myself or using something like [Sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/sigh)

Comment: I was beginning to wonder why am I not doing this manually. XCode seems not to work more that it works, not only on profiles but on everything. Thanks for the info man I'll check **Sigh** out